# Only one active task at any time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have several timers with different intervals. Tasks can be long running and they may overlap, but at any time I must be sure only one task is active. I have the following code with a bool variable which I am setting in event handlers:

```
public partial class SomeService : ServiceBase
{
    private volatile bool IsActive;
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer1;
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer2;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer1.Interval = ConfigurationManager.ImportEveryMinute1 * 60 * 1000;
        Timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer1_Elapsed);
        Timer1.Start();

        Timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer2.Interval = ConfigurationManager.ImportEveryMinute2 * 60 * 1000;
        Timer2.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer2_Elapsed);
        Timer2.Start();
    }

    private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsActive)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            DoSomeStuff1();
            IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    private void Timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsActive)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            DoSomeStuff2();
            IsActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me if `volatile` keyword is sufficient in my case or I should use locking or may be there is some better way for doing this?

Comment: How about locking + async await ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your solution it can happen that

- some timed operations could not processed, because the code doesn't stop and wait till `IsActive` get true.
- it can happened that your two operations run on the same time. Because read and write on `IsActive` are two operations

I suggest the `lock` solution.

```
private static object LockObj = new object();

private void Timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    lock(LockObj) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: This should be done with a `Semafore`, not with `Monitor`

Answer (score 2):

u can use [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    DoSomeStuff1();
    semaphore.Release();
}

private void Timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    DoSomeStuff2();
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: This is more scalable solution than accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, on the contrary, using `volatile` just ensures that when having multiple threads, each of them will always see the latest value. It doesn't help in synchronizing between the threads.

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.
>
> The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access.

Imagine that both threads arrive at the

```
if (!IsActive)
```

They both see the latest value (`false`).
One advances, then the other. Now they are both inside.

If you want to thread synchronization, you'll have to use some sort of locking mechanism like  `lock`.

Notice that with your implementation (event if it worked) the threads are not waiting for each other, they simply exit if the other one is active.

You might want to check out [dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), it might fit your needs better.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your timers with something like this:

```
private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(IsActive)
    {
        DoSomeStuff1();
    }
}

private void Timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(IsActive)
    {
        DoSomeStuff2();
    }
}
```

Comment: bool' is not a reference type as required by the lock statement https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=bool%27+is+not+a+reference+type+as+required+by+the+lock+statement&oq=bool+is+not+a+ref&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.5229j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Oops, you are correct.   Change bool IsActive to object IsActive